# how to look if List exists in DB in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a springboot application where I am saving a list with my Meeting Entity. I can save my entities all at once, but I want to check before each save if one entity inside my list already exists inside my Db and then just save the ones which are not inside. But I am kinda stuck and do not know how to do it. Could someone look at my code and give me an advice?

MeetingController:

```
  @PostMapping("/")
public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody List<Meeting> meeting){
    List<Meeting> exist =
            meetingService.findAllMeetingsWithName(meeting.stream().map(m -> m.getMeetingName()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    meeting.removeAll(exist);
    meetingService.saveMeeting(meeting);
}
```

MeetingService:

```
public void saveMeeting(List<Meeting> meeting){

        meetingRepository.saveAll(meeting);

    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting, Long> {
}
```

Comment: I think you want to actually merge data. Why don't you load your entities in a Set<Meeting> and persist it back, after adding the Meetings?

Comment: what do you mean? I am new to spring to be honest so I did the first thing which came to my mind

Comment: your saveMeeting() could retrieve all meetings first, add them to a Set, then you could add List<Meeting> meeting into this set and only after that you would call meetingRepository.saveAll(meeting). Of course, I am assuming you have a quantity of Meetings that fit your primary memory.

Comment: But if I add both to the same set would they not be duplicated the values?

Answer (score 1):

This is the functionality that you want

```
   @Transactional
   public void saveMeeting(List<Meeting> meeting){

        List<Meeting> alreadyExist = meetingRepository.findByMeetingNameIn(meeting.stream().map(m -> m.getMeetingName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        meeting.removeAll(alreadyExist);
        meetingRepository.saveAll(meeting);

    }
```

and then just define that repository method

```
@Repository
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting, Long> {

  List<Meeting> findByMeetingNameIn (List<String> meetingNames);

}
```

**Remember to override `equals` and `hashcode` in Meeting entity to consider the `id` field.**

Comment: Hi the only Unique field is the id. But I use the meetingName to find every meeting inside the db. And then I want to check if the whole Object is existing if yes then do nothing if no then save it.

Comment: Then I was right to be proactive in my previous answer. Take my updated version of the answer

Comment: Hi, I updated my controller class according to your answer as far as I understood it but still the duplicates are saved

Comment: your Meeting class must have equals and hashcode to consider only id field as I have mentioned already in my answer

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: search how to override equals and hashcode methods and when you make it make sure to use the id field for that override

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html

Comment: @haso please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it has solved the issue :)

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and then report back :) you helped me a few steps so I will upvote now and if it workes completely tomorrow then I’ll tick it 

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your meetings are in the DB. Try this.

```
 List<Meeting> findByValueIn(List<Meeting> values);
```

Comment: How could I do it so it will check for every sent entity? It is a list thats why I am asking

Comment: Here also you're sending a list

Answer (score 0):

Since you already are planning to use JpaRepository, take advantage of the @Query and batch queries

```
@Repository
//custom query using IN
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting, Long>
{
  @Query("SELECT m from MEETING m where m.name IN (:names)")
  public List<Meetings> findAllMeetingWithNames(List<String> meetings)
}

@Service
class MeetingService{

    private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;
    ...
    //other code....

    @Autowired
    public MeetingService(MeetingRepository meetingRepository){
      this.meetingRepository = meetingRepository;  
    }
    
    public void saveAllMeetings(List<Meeting> meetings){
        //call repository custom query here
        names = meetings.stream()
            .map((m) -> m.name)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Meeting> existingMeetings = meetingRepository.findAllMeetingWithNames(names);
        //delete using a single query
        meetingRepository.deleteAllInBatch(existingMeetings);
        meetingRepository.saveAllAndFlush(meetings);
        
    }
    .....
}
```